# Unity lighting and Shading for tilemaps

Tags: unity-game-engine, lighting, pixel-shading

My team and I are working on a Unity game and I'm having trouble getting my shadows right for when I use different tiles. I want it to appear smooth for the terrain like in the 2nd picture. I can accomplish that by using one type of tile and only one but I wanted to use multiple tiles for a better visual appeal. Any suggestions on this? Or am I lacking more information.... Please let me know.

Thanks![image]

I've tried changing the mode from chunk to individual but that didn't help it. I didn't really see a post on this yet either. Some of the videos I've followed they're using one tile versus multiple like I'm wanting to do. [image]

Comment: I'm using Unity version 2021.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.